# What is the "Daily Life" of a program in TRON?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

At least after the movie Tron:Legacy we know, that programs do use recreation facilities and do interact socially.

So my question is, what is the daily life of a program inside "The Grid". Do they sleep, do they wake up? Do they drive to work? They seem to consume energy in their spare time - how is spare time defined for a Tron program.

BUt actually I am asking about the daily life of a program, maybe it can be visualized like the "lifecycle" of an real program. Starting, Do Job, Unload.

I didn't remember that programs in Tron do dissappear when finishing a job (unloading) - so could it be considered, that a program have spare time after finishing a job and what would they do in that time?

This question sounds a bit wierd but following the Tron-Universe I would be interested in opinions how others think about the spare time of programs.

Comment: I think this would be too broad and or opinion based to get good answers, but the Star Trek novel "Memory Prime" by Garfield Reeves-Stevens explores this with sentient programs called the "Pathfinders". It's a rather interesting premise on how little time user requests take and what they do with the rest of their time.

Comment: Between the books, comics, games and TV series, I'd imagine this is at least partially addressed. I haven't watched it, but the episode synopsis for [Tron Uprising](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron:_Uprising) sounds like they go into it at least a little - with things like curfews mentioned.

Comment: Maybe Garbage Collection ?

Answer (score 3):

They have jobs (the thing they were programmed for) and a social life, similar to us.  It was depicted in the series [Tron: Uprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tron:_Uprising).

The main character, Beck, works at a garage repairing vehicles (like the bikes we all know so well, among others), along with his friends Mara and Zed.  They often hang out at the 0001001 Club after work.

When General Tesler tries to take over Argon City for Clu, Beck starts a double life, where he has to keep up appearances at work and with his friends while trying to stop Tesler's plans.  He is aided by a damaged Tron, who is impressed with Beck being able to overcome his programming as a mechanic to become a terrorist known as the Renegade.

[Programs dancing at the 0001001 Club, from the Tron wikia](http://tron.wikia.com/wiki/0001001_Club):

[image: 0001001 Club]

Comment: So, basically, Tron happens inside... Sims?